Expansion in Latex3 when transforming an input and forwarding it to another function
There are still a lot of mystery around expansion in LaTeX for me, but even given that, there is something I don't understand in LaTeX3. Let's say (just for the example), that I want to test whether something is lowercase by comparing an argument #1 to its lowercase version \str_lowercase:n{#1} and using \str_if_eq. This might lead to strange behaviour when #1 is a macro but that's fine, for the example, it's the behaviour I'm expecting.
So what I would like is before injecting them as arguments in \str_if_eq is to have #1 and \str_lowercase:n{#1}, at the same "stage" of expansion (if #1 was an expanded macro, then \str_lowercase:n{#1} should be the lowercase version of the expanded macro, if #1 is a macro, then \str_lowercase:n{#1} should the lowercase version of that unexpanded macro treated as a string).
My guess is that \str_lowercase:n{#1} should be expanded once, but given the result I'm getting, I guess I am misunderstanding how expansion works.
Here is my test code:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \is_lowercase_e:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \exp_args:Ne \__is_lowercase:nn{\str_lowercase:n{#1}}{#1}
}
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \is_lowercase_o:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \exp_args:No \__is_lowercase:nn{\str_lowercase:n{#1}}{#1}
}
\cs_new:Npn \__is_lowercase:nn #1#2{
    \str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \fancycheck_is_lowercase:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\is_lowercase_e:nTF{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns TRUE
\is_lowercase_e:nTF{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns FALSE
\is_lowercase_o:nTF{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns FALSE (why?)
\is_lowercase_o:nTF{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE}   % returns FALSE
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Currently:

Only \exp_args:Ne give me the expected result and not \exp_args:No even though I would expect only one expansion to be needed
But if I do \exp_args:Ne then full expansion will happen and if #1 is a macro, it will be expanded also, and I do not want that
I am not even sure that I need to use \exp_args:Ne for what I'm trying to do

QUESTIONS:

How to achieve what I want (the example may be silly, but at least it illustrates the problem I am trying to solve)?
Why one expansion does not seem to work?
Could you explain what happens during expansion so that one expansion does not seem to work?


You don't need xparse, unless you're using a rather old LaTeX kernel.
Your _o conditional cannot work, because you're just expanding \str_lowercase:n one level.
In order to see what happens, I'll add \tl_show:n to see what's actually passed as #1:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \is_lowercase_e:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \exp_args:Ne \__is_lowercase:nn{\str_lowercase:n{#1}}{#1}
}
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \is_lowercase_o:n{p,T,F,TF}{
    \exp_args:No \__is_lowercase:nn{\str_lowercase:n{#1}}{#1}
}
\cs_new:Npn \__is_lowercase:nn #1#2{
  \tl_show:n{#1}
    \str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \fancycheck_is_lowercase:n{e}{p,T,F,TF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\is_lowercase_e:nTF{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns TRUE
\is_lowercase_e:nTF{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns FALSE
\is_lowercase_o:nTF{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns FALSE (why?)
\is_lowercase_o:nTF{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE}   % returns FALSE
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

You get
> mytext.
<recently read> }

l.21 \is_lowercase_e:nTF{mytext}
                                {TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns TRUE
?
> mytext.
<recently read> }

l.22 \is_lowercase_e:nTF{MyText}
                                {TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns FALSE
?
> \__str_change_case:nn {mytext}{lowercase}.
<recently read> }

l.23 \is_lowercase_o:nTF{mytext}
                                {TRUE}{FALSE}\\ % returns FALSE (why?)
?
> \__str_change_case:nn {MyText}{lowercase}.
<recently read> }

l.24 \is_lowercase_o:nTF{MyText}
                                {TRUE}{FALSE}   % returns FALSE
?

and the comparison is between the stringified version of \__str_change_case:nn {MyText}{lowercase} and mytext, which obviously returns false.
Avoid o expansion, it's seldom really necessary. However, you're doing the thing the wrong way.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\EislowercaseTF}{mmm}
 {
  \is_lowercase_e:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\OislowercaseTF}{mmm}
 {
  \is_lowercase_o:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \is_lowercase_e:n {p,T,F,TF}
  {
    \__is_lowercase:ee { \str_lowercase:e {#1} } {#1}
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \is_lowercase_o:n {p,T,F,TF}
  {
    \__is_lowercase:ee{ \str_lowercase:o{#1} } {#1}
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__is_lowercase:nn #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__is_lowercase:nn {ee}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_lowercase:n {e,o}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\testA}{lower}
\newcommand{\testB}{NotLower}
\newcommand{\testC}{\testA}
\newcommand{\testD}{\testB}

\begin{document}

\EislowercaseTF{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\EislowercaseTF{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\EislowercaseTF{\testA}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\EislowercaseTF{\testB}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\EislowercaseTF{\testC}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\EislowercaseTF{\testD}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\bigskip

\OislowercaseTF{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\OislowercaseTF{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\OislowercaseTF{\testA}{TRUE}{FALSE} (true)

\OislowercaseTF{\testB}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\OislowercaseTF{\testC}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\OislowercaseTF{\testD}{TRUE}{FALSE} (false)

\end{document}



TeX is a macro expansion language, and although expl3 provides various tools, the underlying 'rules' still apply. That means when you do a single expansion of \str_lowercase:n {#1}, you get exactly the definition of \str_lowercase:n with the placeholder #1 'filled in' with whatever the argument is. It's pretty rare that you know that a macro will require only one expansion, which is why most of expl3 is written around the idea of either not expanding at all or expanding 'all the way', which nowadays is largely a case of apply e-type expansion. String in expl3 are not vulnerable to expansion, so \exp_args:Ne is entirely appropriate.
I would not mark the expansion in your function name: rather, you should be clear whether \vincent_is_lowercase:n expands it's argument or not - if you decide it doesn't, create a variant \vincentis_lowercase:e. Either way, you'd want something like
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \vincent_is_lowercase:n { p , T , F , TF }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_lowercase:n {#1} } { \exp_not:n{#1} }
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }

or if the string should be expanded first
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \vincent_is_lowercase:n { p , T , F , TF }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_lowercase:e {#1} } {#1}
      \prg_return_true:
      \prg_return_false:
  }

Here, you also need to be careful about what you want to test. The str case changing functions are really there for dealing with programmatic strings: largely for the case where you want to auto-generate a command name and predict which parts will be lower/uppercase. You are likely wanting to know something different

If you are dealign with programmatic strings and looking for caseless equality, use \str_casefold:n.
On the other hand, if you are dealing with user text, you need to use the (more expensive and slower) \text_lowercase:n function - this will deal correctly with context-dependent casing, etc.


My examples of directly using TeX primitives should help you to more understand TeX principles and its expansion process. Your given task can be solved:
\def\islowercase #1{%
   \def\tmpa{#1}\lowercase{\def\tmpb{#1}}%
   \ifx\tmpa\tmpb \islowercaseT \else \islowercaseF \fi
}
\def\islowercaseT #1\fi #2#3{\fi #2}
\def\islowercaseF #1\fi #2#3{\fi #3}

\islowercase{mytext}{TRUE}{FALSE} % returns TRUE

\islowercase{MyText}{TRUE}{FALSE} % returns FALSE
\bye

Note the fragment \lowercase{\def\tmpb{#1}}. The TeX primitive \lowercase applies "lowercase" to its argument delimited by { and matched }. If #1 is MyText then the argument of \lowercase is \def\tmpb{MyText}. There are 10 tokens: \def, \tmpb, {, M, y, T, e, x, t, }.  The \lowercase primitive never changes the control sequence tokens, i.e. \def and \tmpb and never does expansion. It transforms only tokens M and T to their lowercase alternatives, so the result is \def\tmpb{mytext} after \lowercase is done. And \tmpa is defined as MyText. The \ifx primitive checks if the following two macros (here \tmpa, \tmpb) are defined equally. It is false, so we expand to the "false result" using \islowercaseF.
This example above needs to give the argument of \islowercase directly, i.e. you cannot expect correct result of \islowercase{\text} where \def\text{MyText} was defined before. If you want to check this, then you can do one single expansion. It can be done by \expandafter which does its work before \islowercaseA is started:
\def\islowercase #1{\expandafter\islowercaseA\expandafter{#1}}
\def\islowercaseA#1{% reads #1 after single expansion by \expandafter
   \def\tmpa{#1}\lowercase{\def\tmpb{#1}}%
   \ifx\tmpa\tmpb \islowercaseT \else \islowercaseF \fi
}
\def\islowercaseT #1\fi #2#3{\fi #2}
\def\islowercaseF #1\fi #2#3{\fi #3}

This example allows not only \islowercase{\text} but \islowercase{Text} too because \expandafter TeX primitive tries to expand the first token of the argument T and it is not expandable, so it does nothing (silently).
If you want to do fully expansion (not only single expansion) of the checked parameter, then you can use following example:
\def\islowercase #1{\expanded{\noexpand\islowercaseA{#1}}}
\def\islowercaseA #1{% reads #1 after fully expansion by \expanded
   \def\tmpa{#1}\lowercase{\def\tmpb{#1}}%
   \ifx\tmpa\tmpb \islowercaseT \else \islowercaseF \fi
}
\def\islowercaseT #1\fi #2#3{\fi #2}
\def\islowercaseF #1\fi #2#3{\fi #3}

